Help on formalization of the proof: If $(a,b] = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_n,b_n]$ (disjoint union), then we can supose $a_{n+1}=b_n \forall n \geq 1$
If $a<b$ are extended numbers for which $(a,b] = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_n,b_n]$, where $((a_n,b_n])_{n \geq 1}$ is a sequence of disjoint intervals such that $a_n \leq b_n$, so it is clear that:
intuitively speaking, “the edges of the intervals must touch (i.e. be equal)”, otherwise their union would have to have a “hole” and could not be an interval,
In other words, we can find a permutation $j: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}: n \mapsto j_n$ for which $a_{j_n+1}= b_{j_n} \forall n\geq 1 $
Even though it seems obvious, this seems to be part of the group of obvious things that are difficult to prove (at least I found it difficult to formalize the proof). Could someone help me to formalize the argumentation?

How do you think about: $$(-1,1]=(-1,0]\cup\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}(2^{-n},2^{-n+1}]$$

Indeed, you can't order the sequence such that $a_n<a_{n+1}$  because there would be no $(a_n,b_n]$ which contains $b,$ unless you allow empty intervals and the sequence is essentially finite.

@copper.hat That doesn't work, because there is no ensuring that when you order by $a_n$ you get a well-ordering equivalent to $\mathbb N.$ in fact, unless there are only finitely many non-empty intervals, it can't be.

I made the ordinal mistake of replying without thinking.
